# Can we 'get passive' without 'by'?

Tags: sentence-construction

I read the below sentence somewhere. My question is can we use 'get passive' without by?

> He might get carried away in being a TV reality star rather than being a boxer.

Should  we use 'by' instead of 'in' preposition?

Answer (score 0):

"Carried" is not a passive here. It could be if it referred to somebody literally picking him up and carrying him:

> He got carried away by an ambulance (agent)
>
> He got carried away in an ambulance (not agent, but prepositional phrase giving additional information).

But this idiomatic use of *get carried away* is not a passive: it's unusual to say *The music carried me away*. "Carried" is an adjective, complement of "get".

Normally the idiom may be followed by a "by" phrase, but this is only loosely an agent. "He got carried away by the music."

I find the "in" here a bit strange, but I think it has a different meaning from "by": not a kind of agent, but a kind of field or domain.

Comment: If 'in' is removed then ?

Comment: @Rocky: what are you asking? If "He got carried away being ... " is grammatical? Probably, but it's not clear what the grammatical function of the "being" clause would then be.

Comment: If we remove 'in' then will it change the meaning? He might get carried away being a TV reality star rather than being a boxer.